# MIPS instruction - error

Tags: mips

Why does the instruction
`lw $s0,1($s1)` 
has got an answer which is not defined ? 
`unaligned address` when `$s1` pointing to a word which start in an address which is a multiple of 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being that the effective address you are trying to read is located at an unaligned address.
The instruction you are issuing tries to read a word starting at address `$s1 + 1`.

What has to be word-aligned (multiple of 4) to read a word is the effective address. In this case, as `$s1` is already aligned, adding `1` will get an unaligned effective address.